# Repeat GUI interface, do a little modify or a new one?

Tags: css, html

I am doing a Web Software develop with HTML, Javascript and CSS. Now I have several **div** s, each one is a interface of a functionality. Some of them are quite same, maybe only titles are different. So my question is here: Should I change the existing div with some code, or a new **div** with all elements repeat there. Which is a better design. I knew there is a principle named DIY, and I want to follow it.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to repeat your html...

```
<div class="module">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="module">
<h1>Another title</h1>
<p>...</p>
</div>
```

But not your css:

```
.module {
width: 300;
float: left;
}

.module h1 {
font-size: 18px;
}
```

HTML is a markup language, and as such it's meant to be repeated. In fact, it's a sign that you are modularizing right. If things start to get complex ("damn, I need to put an h2 below every h1 in every div.module!") you can look into a programming language for the web, then the DRY principle applies.

Comment: I'd do `.module .heading` instead of `.module h1` so that the "heading" can be any tag it wants to in the future.